# Фон не формы а панели

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

У меня есть форма, на ней панель, у этой панели есть определенный фон. На панели есть кнопка у которой в свойствах указан цвет фона - `Transparent`. И получается так что у кнопки теперь фон формы, а не панели. Как исправить? Сижу туплю не могу понять.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Кнопка точно на панели? т.е. есть control?

Comment: Я поставил панели visible: false и кнопка тоже пропала, так что думаю да, она на панели

Comment: Является ли панель родителем `parent` кнопки?

Comment: Так не получится, скорее всего. С прозрачностью в WinForms дело обстоит плохо. Придётся отрисовывать на кнопке тот же фон со смещением.

Comment: Можно просто наследовать фон панели или другого объекта при инициализации
`this.button2.BackColor = this.panel1.BackColor;`

Comment: блин, фиговенько, тоесть надо парится со смещением, да?

Comment: с каким смещение?

Comment: Если я просто выставлю такой же фон, то кнопка не будет "прозрачной". Представь что у меня фон попугай, и кнопка стоит по центру, тогда внутри кнопки просто будет маленький такой же фон, не будет прозрачности

Comment: Так, обновление, кнопка вообще не принимает ни чей фон, она просто не становится прозрачной, от слова совсем. И другие ее свойства тоже работают с перебоями, например если я убираю рамку то (о чудо) она остается.

Comment: Попробуйте сделать BackColor каким-нибудь левым цветом (например LimeGreen), а потом приравняйте TransParencyKey к тому же цвету.

Comment: А вообще, надо бы добавить какой-нибудь код или описание проекта. Может баг не в самой кнопке, а в форме в целом

Comment: Я тупой)) Простите что отвлек, поставил стиль кнопки flat - все заработало

Answer (score 2):

С проблемой разобрался. Надо было поставить стиль кнопки не `Standart`, а `Flat`.